# What are JCL Alternitives for Embeded Applications?

Tags: lua, scripting, tcl, jcl, process-control

What are modern alternatives for IBM's old JCL (Job Control Language) scripting language?

For the past several years a client is working on a rewrite/overhaul of their old Mainframe system porting over to the cloud. The rewrite is largely in C# .NET Framework, with a smattering of C++ creating a VM simulating the old mainframe on Azure servers. Right now they are running their old JCL to handle large parts of their database in the new rewrite.

For those that aren't as familiar with JCL in a legacy environment, the client is using it to point to parts of the database, call applications/processes with parameters, and pipe file-I/O to/from the relative applications. It pretty much reads like the old punch-cards, and doesn't have any personal processing power (basic arithmetic/logic key words, memory handling, or use of any kind of module/library expansions).

Right now their looking at Lua or TCL as potential replacements to embed in their new system.

What are alternative languages you have used for process control scripting? Pros? Cons?

Comment: Any scripting language would solve a scripting task :-)  Lua is the most easy to embed in a C host application, but has very few ready-to-use libraries.

Comment: First, JCL does have some of those capabilities, and second, JCL isn't a scripting language.  REXX is a scripting language.  JCL is much more analogous to a CLI for z/OS, where you're specifying a program to run, various arguments to the program, and information about what data to run the program against.  There's some amount of macro/symbol capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also look at Python or (given that you're also using C# and so probably considering running on Windows) Powershell. In a Unix environment, bash would be the first option (even if it was one you then reject).

This isn't something that has a definite answer though, at least with the small amount of information you have provided; there are *lots* of options. As long as you have language or basic library support for the operations you need, you should be able to make that work.

Comment: What job control advantage does Python have over some of the other embedded scripting languages mentioned above?

Comment: I had proposed Powershell to them a while back, but they felt that it was to complex to hand to their product servicing team. Thus the interest in Lua for it's simpler syntax, and ease to learn.